# JavaScript Audio Doubled

Tags: javascript, audio

When this code executes, it actually plays the song twice, just with one slightly delayed.

```
var audio = new Audio('../SuradMisterComputer/Audio/TheSkylabPlan.mp3');

audio.load();
audio.play();
```

Comment: Do you have a working example?

Comment: You use [load()](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/av_met_load.asp) to reload a video or audio after the src property has changed. You only need to load up the audio or video, check that it's loaded via its [built in events](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/av_event_canplay.asp) and then play() it.